# Identification of a signed measure

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

in the book "Limit theorems of stochastic processes" by Jacod/Shyraev $\nu$ is defined as the set of all real valued prcesses $A$ with $A_0=0$ that are cadlag, adapted and whose each path has finite variation over each finite interval $[0,t]$.

The book now says that each path of an element of $\nu$ can be identified with a signed measure. Can someone provide me with a link to a proof?

I know that there is a bijection between the set of measures and the set of distribution functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $\mu([b,c]) = f(c)-f(b)$ ?

Comment: If f is your distribution function, then this defines a probability measure which has f as distribution function. Or what do you mean by your comment?

Comment: $f$ is a path of one of your process

Comment: @user1952009 I see. Do you have a link for the proof? I assume the proof for measures can be used, but to have the proof would be better for me.

Comment: a proof of what ? it seems obvious to me $\mu$ is a signed measure

Comment: There is a bijection between the set of measures and the set of distribution functions on $\mathbb{R}$. My question is if there is something analogue to signed measures. Is there a bijection between the set of all signed measures and all functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with finite variation over each finite interval $[0,t]$. Otherwise the word "identify" is wrong in my opinion? Clearly, $\mu$ is a signed measure for the path f.

Comment: @user1952009 I mean, the path f is the distribution function of a signed measure. But why is it true, that there is only one signed measure for a path f? Otherwise the definition of $(H*S)_t(\omega)$ in the book i have mentioned would not work.

Answer (score 2):

Summarizing comments of @user1952009, given a path of your stochastic process $A(\cdot, \omega)$ over $t\in \Bbb R$ you can define a measure $\mu_{A(\cdot, \omega)}$ as follows: 
$$
\mu_{A(\cdot, \omega)}([s,y]) = A(t,\omega) - A(s,\omega) \tag{1}
$$
and extend it to all Borel subsets of $\Bbb R$ using e.g. Caratheodory extension theorem. Since $A$ does not have to be monotonically increasing, in general $\mu_{A(\cdot, \omega)}$ is a signed (rather than positive) measure. One condition that signed measure has to satisfy is to have a finite total variation, which is secured by the fact that each sample path of $A$ is of finite variation.